# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'className')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have updated the jQuery version in the application and I am getting an error in the DatePickerComponent with jQuery 3.5.0.here i am getting error on .ClassName; i don't know what to do about it

```
...
else {
    if (myOwnFormat == 'HH:mm:ss' || myOwnFormat == 'HH:mm') {
        var className = document.getElementById("icon_" + pickerId).className;
        $("#icon_" + pickerId).removeClass(className).addClass("alarm_clock");
    }
    return myOwnFormat;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is because `document.getElementById("icon_" + pickerId)` is not returning an element.

Comment: You're reading the class in order to remove it - just remove it.  `$("#icon_..").attr("class", "hcm-grid_calar_satt")`

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("icon_" + pickerId)` is returning null and you are trying to get .className from null. This should fix your error.

```
else {
  if (myOwnFormat == 'HH:mm:ss' || myOwnFormat == 'HH:mm') {
    if(document.getElementById("icon_" + pickerId)) {
       var className = document.getElementById("icon_" + pickerId).className;
       $("#icon_" + pickerId).removeClass(className).addClass("hcm-grid_calar_saat");
    }
  }
  return myOwnFormat;
}
```

Comment: Minor improvement: `var icon = document.getElementById("icon_" + pickerId; if (icon) { var className = icon.className` - try to reduce the number of DOM actions.  On its own it's a micro-optimisation, but if it's called 1000+ times it will have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

As part of increasing the Security features as part of Spring 22 Release, Salesforce has moved few components to Private API. resulting which this error is being popped-up.
Unfortunately this was not mentioned in the release notes, but you can find it in the console with "sfdc-lightning/charts/vbar.js has been deprecated. Please update your code to use lightning-vbar-chart".

The workaround would be using the standard 'Report Chart' component in lightning page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30902378)